# How to practically decide the size of a segment (or number of segments) in a distributed transmission line of some given length?

Tags: transmission-line

I want to know in a practical scenario, what is the least optimal size that is as good as infinitesimally small value? I mean practically we can't take infinitesimally small segments, so with what size are we better off...? And how to arrive at that quantity?)

(Another related query, Does this optimal size depends on the wavelength of the wave which is travelling on wire?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want each lumped segment to be significantly less in equivalent length compared to one-quarter of one wavelength of the highest frequency in the spectrum you are are interested in.

A good rule of thumb is about one-tenth to about one-hundredth of the shortest wavelength. To get better accuracy use a shorter lump in terms of wavelength AND, don't forget that an electrical signal travelling down a cable will not travel at the speed of light but circa 0.65x the speed of light hence, you should take this into account when calculating.

> *Another related query, Does this optimal size depends on the
> wavelength of the wave which is travelling on wire?*

It totally depends on it.

Comment: How did you arrive at the quantity - **quarter of one wavelength of the highest frequency**? Can you please present mathematical derivations?

Thank You

Comment: @n_upp I could but I won't. Your original question did not ask for this (a massive undertaking) and, if it had, I wouldn't have made an answer based on my extensive practical knowledge on the subject. There are tons of examples on the internet about transmission line theory and there are free simulators available that model these things in great detail. I shouldn't try and repeat these offerings in my answer. You were implying "practical" and you mentioned that word on two occasions in your question. Try searching for telegrapher's equations.